# Audio decoder (mp3) is not present

Tags: codecs

I have installed ubuntu13.10. My sound card is not having any problem as start up sound was very clear. Bt when I played songs and movies an error occurred giving that mp3 decoder is not present. So which type of driver or software do I need install now.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the ubuntu-restricted-extras package.

Open the software and type "ubuntu-restricted-extras" and install the package or open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Enter your password and try playing the audio file again.